# How to use FORMAT ( Employee.Salary,'C',EN-US) in SUM statement ? Getting error 'Conversion Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I need to display 'tax wage' column in US $ format IN SQL using FORMAT function.
I am using Microsoft SQL server. Can someone please help?
Getting error:

> "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$17,037.72' to data type int."

Below is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.ID, EMPLOYEE.NAME, P.DEDCODE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN P.DEDCODE ='SS2' THEN FORMAT(P.AMOUNT,'C','EN-US') ELSE 0 END) AS 'TAX WAGE'
FROM EMPLOYEE
JOIN P ON EMPLOYEE.ID = P.ID and EMPLOYEE.COMPANY = P.COMPANY 
WHERE
      P.DEDCODE ='SS2'
      AND P.YEAR ='2018'
GROUP BY 
      EMPLOYEE.ID,
      EMPLOYEE.NAME,
      P.DEDCODE
```

I expect the tax wage column to have $70.5 as output instead of simple number 70.5

Answer (score 2):

Your format function should be on `SUM()`:

```
FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN P.DEDCODE = 'SS2' THEN P.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END),'C','EN-US') AS [TAX WAGE]
```

You already included `WHERE` clause with `P.DEDCODE ='SS2'` then why you need conditional aggregation, it should be only

```
SELECT . . . , 
       FORMAT(SUM(P.DEDCODE),'C','EN-US') AS [TAX WAGE]
. . .
```

Comment: Well, he forgot to include the sum inside of the format - but the general idea is correct.

Comment: @SMor. . .  Thank you.